# Can we take photos from a service without any GUI / Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service

This may be asked many times but no one has answered it properly. What I am trying to do here is starting a service which takes photos automatically after 5 minutes. I have used alarmmanager class to trigger the service every 5 minutes. I made it work on some devices but on some I got a error saying camera service died.

Now This can be achieved on lower api levels quite easily, but on android 4.0 and up I heard that android make sure that no pictures are taken without a preview. It still works on some devices but not for all. You can set the width and height of preview to 1 dip but it will not fulfil the goal of taking pictures from the service without any activity.

I would like to know if anyone has made this to work ? Or its just impossible to do ?

Comment: IP Webcam seems to be doing this, but I could not find a way to reproduce it. I would be really grateful if somebody had a solution for this.